# Can a program execute another program without the shell as an intermediate?

Tags: shell, kernel, system-calls

This might be a silly question.  Can a program written for Linux (for example written in Golang), invoke a system call to execute another program directly, or does it have to call the shell first and let it run the other program? I don't mean replacing the current program. Let's say I have `program1` which is a web-server and constantly running, can it execute `program2` by directly reaching out to the kernel and using a relevant system call, or is it going through the shell first? If it's not using the shell, are there specific cases where you have to use the shell in a program to do some stuff? If so what would that be? Would appreciate any infos.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/: "Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Can I run a program without using the shell as an intermediary?

Yes: in exactly the same way that it would launch a shell.

Use `exec`: but this replaces the current process.

Use `fork`: to create a new process, then `exec` to replace it. There are other useful syscalls that the shell uses. `pipe`: to make a pipe. `dup`: to attach pipe to `stdin` or `stdout`.

There are often higher level libraries to do this. These allow your code to work on other OSes (such as Microsoft's Windows). They will combine several of these syscalls (e.g. to synthesise a `create_process` call).

It may seem that forking a process then replacing it will be slow. It is not. It is faster than creating a thread on MS-Windows. `fork` is very efficient: it defers most of the work, so often never has to do it.

### Is there any time where I would have to use a shell, when running a program from another?

Only if it is a shell script. However, you may wish to use its services: globing, redirection, etc. I think golang has good enough libraries to do this though, so you should not need the shell.